# Why does cx_freeze includes modules I have not imported

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I am using cx_freeze on Windows for a script I have and it includes modules that I have not imported in my script like numpy, scipy and pandas. I am new to cx_freeze so I use cxfreeze-quickstart. The issue is that the result size is 155 MB.

My imports are the following:

```
import urllib2
import json
import datetime
from xlwings import Workbook, Range, Chart, Sheet, RgbColor
```

Answer (score 3):

I know nothng about cx_freeze, but from the xlwings website

http://docs.xlwings.org/installation.html#dependencies

it looks like numpy and pandas are (optional) dependencies.  Scipy is a dependency of Numpy.  So I would assume cx_freeze is picking those up due to the implicit dependencies.

Comment: This is the correct answer - to exclude those, one can use the `excludes` option in `cx_Freeze`.